# ПОтік чи потІк?

Tags: вживання-слів, наголос

В книзі Василя Карп'юка "Ще літо, але вже все зрозуміло" знайшла:

> Недалеко від хати біжить маленький пОтік.
>   Біля потОку завжди гарно та прохолодно.

Як бути з наголосом в цих словах? Змінити наголос — вибір автора? Чи дійсно існує слово "пОтік"?

В тлумачному словнику це слово подане без наголосу. Але наскільки я знаю, налогос повинен бути на "і".

Comment: У тлумачному «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах це слово з наголосом, на «і» ([1](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/потік), [2](//www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=потік), [3](http://sum.in.ua/p/7/409/2)) — просто не всі електроні версії словника точні.

Comment: А там у книзі прямо наголоси стоять? (А яка сторінка?)

Comment: Так, у книзі ці слова з наголосами) 9 сторінка, початок розповіді. Не думаю, що це описка/одрук

Comment: Можливо, автор наголошує ці слова так, як їх вимовляють його персонажі. Мовляв, вони є представниками певного діалекту, де наголошують так (у поляків, наприклад, в словах завжди наголос на передостанньому складі; можливо, це впливає й на деякі українські діалекти поблизу Польщі). Або взагалі підкреслюється особиста (нетипова) вимова певного персонажа.

Answer (score 1):

Жоден з відомих мені словників (зокрема: [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BA), [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), [набір словників на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), [набір словників на E2U](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BA&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)*, [«Орфоепічний словник» Погрібного](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/E_LIB/PDF/ukr0001233.pdf#page=451)) не дають наголосу *по́тік* (лише **поті́к**). Мабуть, це просто описка/одрук (у книзі із тексту запитання).

<sub>* Власне в 1 з 372 траплянь на E2U теж *по́тік*, але це теж схоже на описку/одрук.</sub>